# IDXGISwapChain::ResizeBuffers triggers breakpoint when switching from fullscreen to windowed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, direct3d, dxgi

Whenever my Direct3D 11 application switches from fullscreen to windowed mode, IDXGISwapChain::ResizeBuffers triggers a breakpoint.  In Visual Studio's console, the message "Critical error 0xc0000374" is printed, with no other information.  Apparently this means a heap corruption has occurred.  Okay then.  I can't get any more information about why this occurred because the window obnoxiously obscures my view and prevents me from controlling the visual studio window.

I'm following the suggestions made on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075(v=vs.85).aspx).  By that I mean I copied and pasted the code.

This is my setup code (ignore the lack of error checking):

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swap_chain_desc = { 0 };
swap_chain_desc.BufferCount = 2;
swap_chain_desc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
swap_chain_desc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swap_chain_desc.OutputWindow = window::get();
swap_chain_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swap_chain_desc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
swap_chain_desc.Windowed = TRUE;
swap_chain_desc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;

if (fullscreen == 1) {
    swap_chain_desc.BufferDesc.Width = window::desktop_width();
    swap_chain_desc.BufferDesc.Height = window::desktop_height();
} else {
    swap_chain_desc.BufferDesc.Width = window::width();
    swap_chain_desc.BufferDesc.Height = window::height();
}

HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain (
    NULL,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &swap_chain_desc,
    &m_swap_chain,
    &m_device,
    NULL,
    &m_context
);

ID3D11Texture2D* back_buffer;
hr = m_swap_chain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&back_buffer);

hr = m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(back_buffer, NULL, &m_view);

back_buffer->Release();

m_context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_view, NULL);

D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport = { 0 };
viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

if (fullscreen == 1) {
    viewport.Width = window::desktop_width();
    viewport.Height = window::desktop_height();
} else {
    viewport.Width = window::width();
    viewport.Height = window::height();
}

m_context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

if (fullscreen == 1) {
    m_swap_chain->SetFullscreenState(TRUE, NULL);
}
```

Is there anything there that might have caused this problem?  The rendering code is just a ClearRenderTargetView and Present after a PeekMessage loop, nothing important.

Comment: Turn the debug flag on when creating device and swapchain, then you can get more details about the error. `UINT flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
 flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif 

 HRESULT hr;
 if (FAILED (hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain( NULL, 
     D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
  NULL,
  flags,...`

Comment: @zdd I have that turned on, and the only extra info I get is that some unallocated part of the heap was written to.  I traced all of my code and the address it gives me is completely unrelated to anything - the breakpoint is definitely being triggered by IDXGISwapChain::ResizeBuffers (to which I am passing no addresses, and the object itself is valid), though, since removing that line and its dependents gets rid of the crash.

Comment: Can you post more related code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed by showing the window before setting the swap chain's fullscreen state.  Either call `UpdateWindow(hwnd)` and `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW)` or set the window style to `WS_VISIBLE` when calling `CreateWindow()` or `CreateWindowEx()`, preferably before doing anything DirectX related.